# How to create a multi-page PDF, from directory of jpegs with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, gd

I have a directory of 50 jpegs, 72 dpi, RGB, varying sizes.

I want to create a 50-page PDF 8x10, each image 7x9 max in either direction, 72dpi, RGB. Then a .epub, then a .mobi.

I want to create a second 50-page PDF, 8x6, each image now 7x5 max in either direction, 300dpi, CMYK, rot 90 Counter clockwise (-90?).

I have done this 200 times by hand since 2007 in PS, ID, Acrobat, etc. 3-4 hours to do each. I'm curious as how to approach designing a PHP script to do this. I've used PHP GD to manipulate jpegs (crop and resize) for web pages, but not to create multi-page PDFs.

I'm thinking that all of this has grown up a bit since 2007, and I should be able to in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP, there's a wonderful open-source class: [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). Check it out - the manual explains everything much better than I can.

Comment: I am going to take a break for lunch, but so far I find TCPDF to be interesting.  Picking apart one of the examples, I am not finding documentation for the following , to change the fixed variables: $pdf->Image('tcpdf/images/image_demo.jpg', 15, 140, 75, 113, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

If you know exactly what you want to do with your content, the most useful StackOverflow answers will come in response to code that *you* have written that implements some of what you're looking for.

For PDF generation, check out [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), especially its [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php).  Multiple examples show you how to make multi-page documents.  Example number 9 embeds an image on the page, and number 51 uses an image as a page background.  TCPDF is roughly equivalent to FPDF, with a few more features and ongoing development.

For the epub and mobi formats, you'll need completely different tools.

There is a [format convertor](https://github.com/benskay/PHP-Digital-Format-Convert-Epub-Mobi-PDF) project on Github, but I haven't used it.  It leverages other tools, like the ones below:

I know of [one project](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6115-PHP-Create-ebook-in-EPUB-format-for-ex-Apple-iPad.html) that is a pure-PHP solution for generating epub content.  And [phpMobi](https://github.com/raiju/phpMobi) seems to be an option for .mobi files.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'm looking to put the building blocks together.  Thank You for the excellent direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a break for lunch, but so far I find TCPDF to be interesting.

Picking apart one of the examples, I am not finding documentation for the following , to change the fixed variables:

```
$pdf->Image('tcpdf/images/image_demo.jpg', 15, 140, 75, 113, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

Is there a reference to what the order of the numbers and true/false mean?

Comment: So far, I have hacked away and got most of it to work.  Centered horiz works, middle vertically does not.  drat.

Comment: That actually was pretty painless. 2 hours into hacking the example 009, I got the first step: One of my jpegs, scaled from actual size (45 inches) to 7 inches in points, centered h and v.  The output PDF is too big, so I will work on that next.